# Unable to parse JSON data for Oracle Integration Cloud using JQ

Tags: json, jq

need help to parse the JSON data received from Oracle Integration Cloud. The expected output is mentioned below alongwith the command i am trying to use.

1. JQ command

   `jq '[{id: .id},{integrations: [.integrations[]|{code: .code, version: .version, dependencies: .dependencies|{connections: .connections[]|{id: .id, status: .status}}, .dependencies|{lookups: .lookups}}]}]' output.json`

Error :

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> [{id: .id},{integrations: [.integrations[]|{code: .code, version: .version, dependencies: .dependencies|{connections: .connections[]|{id: .id, status: .status}}, .dependencies|{lookups: .lookups}}]}]

Note : If i run below command to fetch only connections data it works fine

`jq '[{id: .id},{integrations: [.integrations[]|{code: .code, version: .version, dependencies: .dependencies|{connections: .connections[]|{id: .id, status: .status}}}]}]' output.json`

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "SAMPLE_PACKAGE"
  },
  {
    "integrations": [
      {
        "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATION",
        "version": "01.00.0000",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "status": "CONFIGURED"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATIO_LOOKUP",
        "version": "01.00.0000",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "status": "CONFIGURED"
          },
         "lookups": {
           "name": "COMMON_LOOKUP_VARIABLES",
           "status": "CONFIGURED"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "code": "HI_INTEGRATION",
        "version": "01.00.0000",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "status": "CONFIGURED"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

output.json file contains

```
{
  "bartaType": "DEVELOPED",
  "countOfIntegrations": 3,
  "id": "SAMPLE_PACKAGE",
  "integrations": [
    {
      "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATION",
      "dependencies": {
        "connections": [
          {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "lockedFlag": false,
            "name": "Hello World1",
            "role": "SOURCE",
            "status": "CONFIGURED",
            "type": "rest",
            "usage": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      "description": "",
      "eventSubscriptionFlag": false,
      "filmstrip": [
        {
          "code": "HELLO_WORLD1",
          "iconUrl": "/images/rest/rest_icon_46.png",
          "name": "Hello World1",
          "role": "SOURCE",
          "status": "CONFIGURED"
        }
      ],
      "id": "HELLO_INTEGRATION|01.00.0000",
      "lockedFlag": false,
      "name": "HELLO_INTEGRATION",
      "pattern": "Orchestration",
      "patternDescription": "Map Data",
      "payloadTracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "publishFlag": false,
      "scheduleApplicable": false,
      "scheduleDefined": false,
      "status": "ACTIVATED",
      "style": "FREEFORM",
      "styleDescription": "Orchestration",
      "tempCopyExists": false,
      "tracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "version": "01.00.0000",
      "warningMsg": "ACTIVATE_PUBLISH_NO_CONN"
    },
    {
      "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATIO_LOOKUP",
      "dependencies": {
        "connections": [
          {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "lockedFlag": false,
            "name": "Hello World1",
            "role": "SOURCE",
            "status": "CONFIGURED",
            "type": "rest",
            "usage": 6
          }
        ],
        "lookups": [
          {
            "lockedFlag": false,
            "name": "COMMON_LOOKUP_VARIABLES",
            "status": "CONFIGURED",
            "usage": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "description": "",
      "eventSubscriptionFlag": false,
      "filmstrip": [
        {
          "code": "HELLO_WORLD1",
          "iconUrl": "/images/rest/rest_icon_46.png",
          "name": "Hello World1",
          "role": "SOURCE",
          "status": "CONFIGURED"
        }
      ],
      "id": "HELLO_INTEGRATIO_LOOKUP|01.00.0000",
      "lockedFlag": false,
      "name": "HELLO_INTEGRATION_LOOKUP",
      "pattern": "Orchestration",
      "patternDescription": "Map Data",
      "payloadTracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "publishFlag": false,
      "scheduleApplicable": false,
      "scheduleDefined": false,
      "status": "ACTIVATED",
      "style": "FREEFORM",
      "styleDescription": "Orchestration",
      "tempCopyExists": false,
      "tracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "version": "01.00.0000",
      "warningMsg": "ACTIVATE_PUBLISH_NO_CONN"
    },
    {
      "code": "HI_INTEGRATION",
      "dependencies": {
        "connections": [
          {
            "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
            "lockedFlag": false,
            "name": "Hello World1",
            "role": "SOURCE",
            "status": "CONFIGURED",
            "type": "rest",
            "usage": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      "description": "",
      "eventSubscriptionFlag": false,
      "filmstrip": [
        {
          "code": "HELLO_WORLD1",
          "iconUrl": "/images/rest/rest_icon_46.png",
          "name": "Hello World1",
          "role": "SOURCE",
          "status": "CONFIGURED"
        }
      ],
      "id": "HI_INTEGRATION|01.00.0000",
      "lockedFlag": false,
      "name": "HI_INTEGRATION",
      "pattern": "Orchestration",
      "patternDescription": "Map Data",
      "payloadTracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "publishFlag": false,
      "scheduleApplicable": false,
      "scheduleDefined": false,
      "status": "ACTIVATED",
      "style": "FREEFORM",
      "styleDescription": "Orchestration",
      "tempCopyExists": false,
      "tracingEnabledFlag": true,
      "version": "01.00.0000",
      "warningMsg": "ACTIVATE_PUBLISH_NO_CONN"
    }
  ],
  "isCloneAllowed": false,
  "isViewAllowed": false,
  "name": "SAMPLE_PACKAGE",
  "type": "DEVELOPED"
}
```

Comment: Welcome. You need to share the input as well as the output, so we're not left guessing when trying to help you with the jq filter you might need. If that's something you cannot share (security etc) then use a cut down version that illustrates your challenge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `lookups` key is not always present so, you cannot use the `[]` on it. So, instead you can use the `map` function and provide a default before piping to the map function like below

```
[
  { id: .id },
  {
      integrations: [
      .integrations[]|{
        id: .id,
        code: .code,
        dependencies: {
          connections: (.dependencies.connections//[]|map({id,status}))[0],
          lookups: (.dependencies.lookups//[]|map({name,status}))[0]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The `(.dependencies.lookups//[]|map({name,status}))[0]` has the effect of passing an empty array to the map function which results in a `null` value when accessing the first element.

See in action https://jqplay.org/s/zQBkHtnzOd1

Comment: Thanks for your response!! . So we are traversing the array lookups from dependencies and passing the result to map function to extract the key-values name and status. If lookup array not found we are passing an empty array [0] so it prints null . Could you please explain the effect of using //[] while traversing ( .dependencies.lookups//[]|map({name,status}))[0]

Answer (score 0):

The provided JQ statement works fine for single elements in the array , but incase the array contains multiple elements it only fetches the first element. Also i updated the dependencies object to capture all the arrays ( connections,lookups,certificates,libraries,integrations)
Below is the modified one. Please suggest for any better options.

```
[   
 { id: .id },   
    { 
       integrations: [
       .integrations[]|{
           id: .id,
           code: .code,
             dependencies: {
              connections: (.dependencies.connections//[]|map({id,status})),
              lookups: (.dependencies.lookups//[]|map({name,status})),
              certificates: (.dependencies.certificates//[]|map({id,status})),
              libraries: (.dependencies.libraries//[]|map({code,status,version})),        
              integrations: (.dependencies.integrations//[]|map({code,version}))         
              }       
             }     
        ]   
    } 
]|del(..|select(.==[]))
```

Note: To remove the empty arrays del function is added which is giving the below output :

```
[
  {
    "id": "SAMPLE_PACKAGE"
  },
  {
    "integrations": [
      {
        "id": "HELLO_INTEGRATION|01.00.0000",
        "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATION",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": [
            {
              "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
              "status": "CONFIGURED"
            },
            {
              "id": "HELLO_WORLD2",
              "status": "CONFIGURED"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "HELLO_INTEGRATIO_LOOKUP|01.00.0000",
        "code": "HELLO_INTEGRATIO_LOOKUP",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": [
            {
              "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
              "status": "CONFIGURED"
            }
          ],
          "lookups": [
            {
              "name": "COMMON_LOOKUP_VARIABLES",
              "status": "CONFIGURED"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "HI_INTEGRATION|01.00.0000",
        "code": "HI_INTEGRATION",
        "dependencies": {
          "connections": [
            {
              "id": "HELLO_WORLD1",
              "status": "CONFIGURED"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```